# Docker pushing containers to private registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose

I have an app which uses several docker containers:

1. NGINX container
2. NodeJS sails app container
3. Redis cache container

Since I'm using existing images for two of the above containers, I also have two cached containers:

4. alpine
5. redis

I'm trying to push my containers (1, 2, & 3) to AWS Elastic Container Registry (ECR). I've been able to do this, but have noticed that my cached containers (4 & 5) get pushed too.

I'm building the containers using `docker-compose`, and then tagging like so:

`docker tag -f nodejs_app:latest <repository URL>:latest`

After logging into ECR with `docker login`, I push using this command:

`docker push <repository URL>:latest`

Docker then pushes all 5 containers up into the registry. **How do I only push the containers that I care about and not the cached ones too?**

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I only push the containers that I care about and not the cached ones too?

You don't.

Docker images (not *containers*; a container is what you get when you boot an *image*) are built from layers.  Your `nginx` image, for example, consists of all the layers from the `alpine` image, followed by any layers that are created as the result of your `Dockerfile`.

In order for your new image to be stored in a private repository, *all the underlying layers need to be available*.  This means that in addition to the layers you create via your `Dockerfile`, all the layers from the `alpine` image also need to be pushed to the repository as well.

So if you build an image on top of the `alpine` image and push it to a private repository, the `alpine` image will get pushed there as well.

Comment: Great answer, thank you for the clarification. I suspected I could have been missing something fundamental in my understanding.